# Ruby's ERB like feature in python

Tags: python, ruby, python-2.7

I've configuration files some formatted as `json` some formatted as `yaml`. I want to be able to read those configuration files with values which comes as environment variables. for example:

```
{"username":"Dan", "password":"<%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD']%>"}
```

Which means that password is retrieved when loading the json file from environment variable and replace the `<%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD']%>` with concrete value.

**Note:1. The syntax mentioned above is like it is being used using ruby's erb only for illustration
       2. I prefer a solution of native python without installing new python packages, but if there no such ,I'll accept this also.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is commonly called *templating*, and you have basically defined a *template language*.

Depending on what *exactly* you want to do, you can use the [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) library from the stdlib. It only does simple variable substitutions, though, as opposed to ERb, which allows *arbitrary* code (including code that deletes all your data, formats your harddisk, starts a backdoor, …).

So, `string.Template` is both *much* less powerful than ERb, but also *much* safer. Your example already demonstrates this, as you cannot even access environment variables from within a template, you would have to pass them in explicitly.

This is the basic usage:

```
from string import Template

s = Template('{"username": "Dan", "password": "$db_password"}')

s.safe_substitute(db_password = 's00persekrit')
# >>> {"username": "Dan", "password": "s00persekrit"}
```

As accessing environment variables isn't possible inside the template, you will have to pass them in to the template explicitly:

```
from string import Template
from os import environ as env

s = Template('{"username": "Dan", "password": "$db_password"}')

s.safe_substitute(db_password = env['DB_PASSWORD'])
# >>> {"username": "Dan", "password": "s00persekrit"}
```

Actually, if you want to give the template access to all environment variables, you should be able to pass the `os.environ` dict directly (you can pass any `dict`-like object for the mapping).

```
from string import Template
from os import environ as env

s = Template('{"username": "Dan", "password": "$DB_PASSWORD"}')

s.safe_substitute(env)
# >>> {"username": "Dan", "password": "s00persekrit"}
```

If you want some more powerful substitutions, then you should look at some other so-called "logic-less" template languages (i.e. languages which only perform simple substitutions but don't allow executing code, and don't allow conditionals or loops). One of those languages is [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) (the templating language used by GitHub), there are implementations in many languages, including [Pystache for Python](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/).

If you want / need more advanced features such as loops, conditionals, etc., you might need to look for more full-featured [template languages](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) such as [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).